When I list all the hidden folders in Linux there are 2 folders with the name . And .. what is the purpose of those two folders
For example
ls -a /ext/Lahore
. .. Bank abc .xyz
Purpose of first two folders

pointers so anything using that directory will know both where it is, and where the directory above it is.
